# How to return custom table types from Npgsql and stored procedures?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to return a custom (composite) type based on an implicit table type.

I have this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE app_user (id CHAR(36) PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
```

Which is mapped to this class definition:

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which is mapped by calling:

```
NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally<ApplicationUser>("app_user");
```

And I'm trying to return a record with this stored procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_by_id(user_id app_user.id%TYPE) RETURNS app_user AS $$
DECLARE
    found_user app_user;
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM app_user
    WHERE id = user_id
    INTO found_user;

    RETURN found_user;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Which I'm calling from C# like this:

```
ApplicationUser user;
using (NpgsqlConnection db = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
{
    db.Open();
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("find_by_id", db))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", userId);
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        user = result == DBNull.Value ? null : (ApplicationUser)result;
    }
}
```

But I get an exception when casting `result` to `ApplicationUser`:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyApp.ApplicationUser'.
```

This is clearly because `result` is just the string `Id`, but why isn't `result` my composite `app_user` object?

I've also tried to return the object with an out parameter, but ran into the exact same exception.  Is what I'm trying to do possible with Npgsql, or do I have to re-build the `ApplicationUser` object manually in C# from the individual columns?

I'm using Npgsql v3.2.0 and PostgreSQL v9.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.  Turned out to be easier than I thought.  All I needed to change was the way the stored procedure was called from C#.

```
ApplicationUser user;
using (NpgsqlConnection db = new NpgsqlConnection(this.connectionString))
{
    db.Open();
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT find_by_id(@user_id);", db))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user_id", userId);
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        user = result == DBNull.Value ? null : (ApplicationUser)result;
    }
}
```

I preferred the other way of invoking the stored procedure, but at least this works!