# User defined postgresql types using Npgsql from F#

Tags: postgresql, f#, npgsql, f#-data, custom-type

We use postgresql's features to the maximum to ease our development effort. We make heavy use of custom types (user defined types) in postgresql; most of our functions and stored procedures either take them as input parameters or return them.

We would like to make use of them from F#'s SqlDataProvider. That means we should somehow be able to tell F# how to map F# user type to postgresql user type. In other words

1. Postgresql has our defined user type post_user_defined
2. F# has our defined user type fsharp_user_defined

We should instruct Npgsql to somehow perform this mapping. My research so far points me to two approaches and none of them are completely clear to me. Any help is appreciated

**Approach 1**

NpgsqlTypes namespace has pre-defined set of postgresql types mapped to .NET out of box. Few of them are classes, others structures. Say I would like to use postgresql's built in type point which is mapped to .NET by Npgsql via NpgsqlPoint. I can map this to application specific data structure like this:

```
let point (x,y) = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlPoint(x,y)
```

(From PostgreSQLTests.fsx)

In this case, postgresql point and NpgsqlPoint (.NET) are already defined. Now I would like to do the same for my custom type.

Suppose the user defined postgresql composite is

```
create type product_t as ( name text, product_type text);
```

And the application data structure (F#) is the record

```
type product_f = {name :string; ptype :string }
```

or a tuple

```
type product_f = string * string
```

How do I tell Npgsql to make use of my type when passed as a parameter to postgresql functions/procedures? It looks like I will need to use NpgsqTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Composite or Npgsql.PostgresCompositeType which doesn't have a constructor that is public.

I am at a dead end here!

**Approach 2**

Taking cue from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337076/how-to-return-custom-table-types-from-npgsql-and-stored-procedures?rq=1), I could create a custom type and register with MapCompositeGlobally and use it to pass to postgresql functions.So, here I try my hand at it

On Postgresql side, the type and functions are respectively

```
CREATE TYPE product_t AS
   (name text,
    product_type text)
```

and

```
func_product(p product_t)  RETURNS void AS
```

And from my application in F#

```
type PgProductType(Name:string,ProductType:string)=
  member this.Name = Name 
  member this.ProductType = ProductType
  new() = PgProductType("","")
Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally<PgProductType>("product_t",null)
```

and then

type Provider = SqlDataProvider

let ctx = Provider.GetDataContext() 
let prd = new PgProductType("F#Product","")
 ctx.Functions.FuncProduct.Invoke(prd);;

```
  ctx.Functions.FuncIproduct.Invoke(prd);;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(29,1): error FS0501: The member or object constructor 'Invoke' takes 0 argument(s) but is here given 1. The requir
ed signature is 'SqlDataProvider<...>.dataContext.Functions.FuncIproduct.Result.Invoke() : Unit'.
```

Its strange to note that the error reports that : **constructor 'Invoke' takes 0 argument(s) but is here given 1**. F# side of things are completely blind to the argument that postgresql function takes. It does recognize that the function FuncIproduct exists but blind to the arguments it takes.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your 1st approach, as you've understood NpgsqlTypes contains some types which Npgsql supports out of the box - but these are only PostgreSQL built-in types. You cannot add a new type into there without changing Npgsql's source code, which isn't something you want to do.

Also, you should understand the difference between user-defined types (which PostgreSQL calls "composite") and totally independent types such as `point`. The latter are full types (similar to `int4`), with their own custom binary representation, while the former aren't.

Your 2nd approach is the right one - Npgsql comes with full support for PostgreSQL composite types. I have no idea how SqlDataProvider functions - I'm assuming this is an F#-specific type provider - but once you've properly mapped your composite via MapCompositeGlobally, Npgsql allows you to write it transparently by setting an NpgsqlParameter's Value to an instance of PgProductType. It may be worth trying to get it working with type providers first.