# Pass Table Valued Parameter from C# to call Postgres Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a stored procedure in Postgres and it has only one input parameter and it is of table type. *I don't want to use Dapper or Entity Framework in C#.*

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test.UpsertListingData(
    p_data Teste.ListingTableType
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Test.Listing (ValuationDate, WHSKU, PlatformCode, Price, MRP)
    VALUES (p_data.ValuationDate, p_data.WHSKU, p_data.PlatformCode,p_data.Price,p_data.MRP)

END;
$$;
```

here is how I am trying to call the stored procedure:

```
    using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT Test.UpsertListingData@p_data)", connection))
{
    var parameter = new NpgsqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "p_data",
        NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Array,
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
        Value = parameters.ToArray()
    };

    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

I have tried sending the data as JSON as well(Failed there as well).
But I am trying to send it as Datatable or as List whose schema matches to the table type. Please suggest the correct way to do this.

Edit: Code in the question is just for example. I am just trying to figure out a way to send table valued parameter from C# side to postgres.

Comment: Here you have an example with explanations: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#commandtypestoredprocedure . Is not ok to invoke it with Select.

Comment: Can't find anything about table valued parameters. @DA

Comment: There's no such thing as a Table Valued Parameter in Postgres. What you have is a composite type. See https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html?tabs=connection If you want multiple rows then you need an array of such types, and you need to redefine your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass composite types to PL/pgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50418348/how-to-pass-composite-types-to-pl-pgsql-function)

Comment: What went wrong when you tried sending the data as JSON? Certainly there is a way to do it.